# Extracting text from a line: Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with regular expressions in Python and I'm struggling with this. 
I have data in a file of lines like this one:

```
|person=[[Old McDonald]]
```

and I just want to be able to extract `Old McDonald` from this line.

I have been trying with this regular expression:

```
matchLine = re.match(r"\|[a-z]+=(\[\[)?[A-Z][a-z]*(\]\])", line)
print matchLine
```

but it doesn't work; `None` is the result each time.

Comment: extract means you are to change `line` ?

Comment: I just want to be able to store Old McDonald from this line, so I can put it in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct `[A-Z][a-z]*` does not match `Old McDonald`.  You probably should use something like `[A-Z][A-Za-z ]*`.  Here is code example:

```
import re
line = '|person=[[Old McDonald]]'
matchLine = re.match ('\|[a-z]+=(?:\[\[)?([A-Z][A-Za-z ]*)\]\]', line)
print matchLine.group (1)
```

The output is `Old McDonald` for me.  If you need to search in the middle of the string, use `re.search` instead of `re.match`:

```
import re
line = 'blahblahblah|person=[[Old McDonald]]blahblahblah'
matchLine = re.search ('\|[a-z]+=(?:\[\[)?([A-Z][A-Za-z ]*)\]\]', line)
print matchLine.group (1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's working for me. I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @user2057841 Are you running my example exactly as it is or you copied my regex to your code?

Comment: Ok, I got it!! Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that `re.match` searches in the beginning of the string only.  If you want to search for possible occurences in the middle of the string, use `re.search` instead.